# Add value to column with logical operator on row R

Tags: r, dataframe, logical-operators

I have a long data frame in R with a column called "Well." Each well occurs more than once in that column. For a small subset of those wells, I want to add a value to an empty column called "Trypan."

So my df looks something like this, but very long.

| Well | Trypan |
| --- | --- |
| A12 | NA |
| B12 | NA |
| C12 | NA |
| ... | NA |
| A12 | NA |
| B12 | NA |
| C12 | NA |

I want to assign a value in the trypan column that is the same for every well called A12.
I don't want to write a whole vector or make a new df and attach/melt it though, that's a pain.

I want to do something as simple as **"if well = A12, Trypan = 90."** But I cannot figure out that syntax!

I have in fact tried googling this but it seems like other people are asking different questions that I cannot apply to my problem. My apologies for this very basic question.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a logical vector with `==` and use that index to assign 90 to those rows in 'Trypan'

```
df1$Trypan[df1$Well == "A12"] <- 90
```

-ouput

```
    Well Trypan
1  A12     90
2  B12     NA
3  C12     NA
4  A12     90
5  B12     NA
6  C12     NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Well = c("A12", "B12", "C12", "A12", "B12", "C12"
), Trypan = c(90, NA, NA, 90, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -6L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
transform(
  df,
  Trypan = replace(Trypan, Well == "A12", 90)
)
```

which gives

```
  Well Trypan
1  A12     90
2  B12     NA
3  C12     NA
4  A12     90
5  B12     NA
6  C12     NA
```

## Data

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Well = c("A12", "B12", "C12", "A12", "B12", "C12"
), Trypan = c(90, NA, NA, 90, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -6L
), class = "data.frame")
```